# SQL,JTable Record number update

Tags: java, sql, jtable

I'm working on project , where I'm using SQL database and `JTable` , I'm trying to come up with method which will repair the order of record id after delete of one record. My idea is something like: 
for example I have records with id 10,11,12 and after delete of record 11 , I want to make record with number 12  to record with number 11 etc. 
.I've have tried do it like:

```
sqledit = "UPDATE records set id = " + i + "where id = " + i + ";";
```

inside a for loop where second parameter would be `i < (number of records in database)`, but I get error

> SEVERE: null java.sql.SQLException: unrecognized token: "0where"

Comment: Maybe you should add a space after the `"` in `"where id`

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? This can be done much more efficiently using a *single* update statement (at least with a modern DBMS). Btw: your loop would not work, because you are essentially doing: `update records set id = 1 where id = 1`. If you delete `id = 11` the statement `update records set id = 11 where id = 11` wouldn't update anything because `id = 11` is no longer there. Having said all that: if `id` is the primary key of that table, "renumbering" does not make any sense whatsoever. There is no need to do this. A pk values has no meaning. So renumbering it is useless.

Comment: You are right about the loop, I'll think about solution in another way not using this id